# Facebook "Like IT" Button with Names

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to show names of people who liked it too?

How can I see "10 People Like This Page", can I get the Names of these people, and show it in stead of counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard "FB Like Button" ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like ) 
Only shows mutual friends who Like the link. As for names, It can show their profile picture and on mouseover their name pops up.